# Как исправить порядок показа модулей в правом столбе в Magento?

Tags: html, magento

Обратил внимание, что в правой колонке, где баннер должен находится первым вверху, становится вторым на некоторых страницах, точнее на всех кроме "посмотреть всё меню"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
В catalog.hml запись такая:

```
<reference name="right">
        <block type="page/html" name="page.right.banner" before="right.reports.product.viewed" template="page/custom/banner.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: Эта часть кода была в default, нужно перенести в catalog_category_layered